# How can i retrieve this value using an alert box?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

On my website i have a html file with the following configuration:

```
<script>
window.Conf.page = window.Conf.page || {};
    
$.extend(Conf.page, {"newNotifications":false,"userId":"125"}
</script>
```

In the same page i need to retrieve the value of `userId` using a script and display it into an alert box. I tried using this script:

```
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByName('userId'))
</script>
```

But i'm getting `[object NodeList]` inside the alert box.

What code could i use to get the value of userId inside the alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
alert(window.Conf.page.userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<script>
  window.Conf.page = window.Conf.page || {}; 
  var json = $.extend(Conf.page, {"newNotifications":false,"userId":"125"});

  alert(json.userId);
</script>
```

or

```xml
<script>
  window.Conf.page = window.Conf.page || {}; 
  Conf.page = $.extend(Conf.page, {"newNotifications":false,"userId":"125"});

  alert(Conf.page.userId);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the value property of the element in the node list, the node list is a list of all the nodes with the name property matching the one you pass in, in the off chance you had two input fields with the name property being the same their index would be 0 and 1 respectively.

```
document.getElementsByName('userId')[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the getElementById if an looking for an HTML tag, or in your case here simply `window.Conf.page.userId` to get the value.

```js
window.pageConf = window.pageConf || {};
$.extend(pageConf, {"newNotifications":false,"userId":"125"});

function onTestClick() {
  var a = document.getElementsByName('userId');
  document.getElementById('myLabelId').innerText = a.length;
  // Result: 0

  document.getElementById('myLabelId').innerText += " " + window.pageConf.userId;
  // Result: 125
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="onTestClick()">Test</button><br/><br/>
<label id="myLabelId"></label>
```

**Having said that, let's talk about "name" in a tag.**

getElementsByName returns an array because Name is not unique to an element. Name is used for mainly 2 things:

1. For postback: When submitting a form, the value of input is posted with the "name" in the tag. For example:

`Comments: <input id='myUniqueLocalId' name='comments' />`

2. To group radio buttons or checkboxes together. Small example:

```js
function onTestClick() {
  var q1 = document.getElementsByName('q1');
  
  document.getElementById('myLabelId').innerText += " " + q1.length + " " + q1[0].value + " " + q1[1].value;
  // Result: 2 Yes No
}
```

```html
Question 1: 
<input type="radio" id="Yes" name="q1" value="Yes" checked>
<label for="Yes">Yes</label><be>
<input type="radio" id="No" name="q1" value="No">
<label for="No">No</label><br>

Question 2:
<input type="radio" id="Yes" name="q2" value="Yes">
<label for="Yes">Yes</label><be>
<input type="radio" id="No" name="q2" value="No" checked>
<label for="No">No</label><br>

<button onclick="onTestClick()">Test</button><br/><br/>

<label id="myLabelId"></label>
```